# Visual Studio 2010 "Preparing Solution" dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

What the crap is this "Preparing Solution" dialog that VS 2010 shows when I open solutions?  Does this show up for everyone or is something screwed up on my install?

Anyone know what its actually doing?

Comment: I know this is just a waste of a comment, but LMFAO.

Comment: @Erick_Robertson Good comment though :)

Comment: I'm guessing that it's doing about the same amount of work VS2008 did when opening a project, but now there's a progress bar on it so you can tell when it's done. But I haven't compared speeds.

Comment: @Erick This is probably a waste of an question, too...  :)  I got frustrated with it this AM and needed to vent somewhere.

Comment: MS Feedback: Preparing to load solution, but never does https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816047/preparing-to-load-solution-but-never-does

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's the official history, from Cameron McColl:

> In Dev10 we invested in improving solution load time by looking at  making the load asynchronous. Unfortunately due to time constraints this work didn’t make it into Dev10 so instead we decided to at least make the user experience slightly better by giving the user feedback on what was going on during solution load. Initially this involved a dialog that presented accurate feedback on how many projects were being loaded along with the name of the currently loading project. Early testing of this experience revealed that there was often a non-trivial delay (i.e. the spinning donut and “not responding” window title) after the projects were loaded and the existence of the dialog made this delay very apparent once the dialog was dismissed. So what is the delay? There are 2 main things going on after the solution projects have been loaded. First all previously loaded documents/editors are reopened and for some designer files this can take a few seconds. Secondly and usually much worse we call `NotifyOnAfterSolutionOpen` which is an extension point in VS. Any subscriber to this event gets to run their code at this point and quite often this code is very expensive. For Dev10 we didn’t have the time to go improve the perf of all of these subscribers and so it was felt that a second dialog was required to make it clear that the Solution Load was still underway. What really sucks about the second dialog is that it doesn’t tell you what part of the code is causing the delay and worse the progress control is the marquee style which means it’s non determinant (unlike the first dialog).
>
> Moving forward we are continuing to investigate ways to make solution load truly asynchronous and as such never show such nasty dialogs.
> In the dialog's defense, our research indicates that most people prefer a modal status dialog over the spinning donut or unresponsive UI. Of course, everyone prefers no delay at all, and we’re working on that for Dev11.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the solutionname.sln.docstates.suo file. If Visual Studio gets stuck reopening the documents that you had open when you last closed the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal as far as I'm aware. It's loading the solution file and performing house-keeping to ensure all the tools are appropriately prepared for you. Not sure what you are getting riled about.

Comment: It annoys me because it was never there before and as I'm watching VS load, it gets to the point where I'd be able to start working on older versions and then its like "OH WAIT, I'M NOT REALLY DONE, I WAS JUST TEASING YOU.  ALL THAT OTHER STUFF I WAS DOING WAS JUST A WASTE OF YOUR TIME.  NOW SIT THERE WHILE I 'PREPARE' YOUR SOLUTION. LOL."  I'll get used to it in time, but every time I open a solution now I get all excited to start working and then I hit this dialog and have to sit there for 10 more seconds.  (Yes this is all petty, but I'm impatient and like to not wait on my computer...)

Comment: I think VS2008, at least, showed the dialog but it was quicker to disappear. Maybe 2010 is doing more work up front to ensure you've got more available as you go into the editor.